# Topological_navigation dependency

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi to all,

I'm trying to test the Topological_navigation but i encountered some dependencies problem.
Apparently, one of the stacks known as graph_mapping_utils is not available in the graph_mapping package but is required by the topological_navigation package. How should i solve it?

Can i also classify whether usage of the camera is the only source to obtain information from the surrounding by the topological_navigation?

Thank for your time

With regards,
Zhiping

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10077/topological_navigation-dependency/) by [zhiping](https://answers.ros.org/users/131/zhiping/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2011-05-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Zhiping, you may not be using the right versions.  In particular, if you follow the rosinstall directions given on http://www.ros.org/wiki/topological_navigation you shouldn't have any dependency problems.  Also, the camera is not needed for this stack — it just assumes a horizontal laser range finder.

---

Originally posted by [bhaskara](https://answers.ros.org/users/95/bhaskara/) with karma: 1479 on 2011-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zhao Cheng](https://answers.ros.org/users/10111/zhao-cheng/) on 2014-03-01**:
Dear Sir
Do you know how to install topological_navigation node into Fuerte version? I run the instruction in the topological_navigation node website, but there is nothing in the desired-topo-nav-location